# Which number will replace the question mark

Tags: number-sequence

Here is a picture of a square. From the square, your task is to find out what number should replace the question mark and find a formula of it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer :**

> [image]

**Description :**

> **1.** $(7 + 2)^2 + 7^2 = 130$
> **2.** $(4 + 3)^2 + 4^2 = 65$
> **3.** $(8 + 5)^2 + 8^2 = 233$
> **4.** $(9 + 6)^2 + 9^2 = 306$

Comment: Seems pretty arbitrary. Why isn't it (6+9)² + 6² = 261? Just because two sides square the bottom number doesn't mean the top and bottom should square the number to the right.